# Creating a Settings Activity on Android P

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-preferences, androidx

My `SettingsActivity` currently extends the Android Studio generated class, `AppCompatPreferenceActivity` which extends [`PreferenceActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity). Each of the preference screens in the activity are displayed using a [`PreferenceFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment); which, as of API level 28, is deprecated. The documentation states you should use the [`PreferenceFragmentCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat) class from the support library as an alternative.

The issue is that `PreferenceFragmentCompat` extends `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` (instead of `android.app.Fragment`) which the `PreferenceActivity` does not support. And there is no `PreferenceActivityCompat` to fill the role of the of the now inconsequential `PreferenceActivity`.

Further confusing the issue; the new `androidx.preference` support library includes its own [`PreferenceFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceFragment) (which extends `android.app.Fragment`) *and* [`PreferenceFragmentCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat) (which extends the new `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`).

I could always recreate the functionality of the `PreferenceActivity` with my own classes, but why would the documentation recommend using the `PreferenceFragmentCompat` without a viable alternative to the `PreferenceActivity`? Am I missing something, or is the current state of the preference libraries not functional?

---

The `SettingsActivity` works as-is for now, but I usually like to try to get ahead of the curve, especially when something becomes deprecated.

Comment: Wanted to add this as a **comment** but didn't have enough reputation :-P Even I myself don't understand a lot of things in it. I, however, have tried various methods of implementing a settings activity and the best one I came across is in the guides itself. [Creating Settings Activity Basic](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/#java)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a PreferenceActivity; a regular AppCompatActivity will serve the purpose just fine. If you want, there is a direct method of making a Settings Activity in your app provided by Android Studio:
[image: How to create a new Settings Activity in Android Studio]